# CSS selectors for labels

Tags: css

Is there a way i can only change styling for the labels that are followed by the input tag only and not by select tag or any other tag

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name>
<label>City</label>
<select>
<option>Chandigarh</option>
<option>Mohali</option>
<option>Delhi</option>
</select>
```

Here , I Want both the labels should have different styling , I have tried selectors but unable to fix it.

Comment: If you may change the markup you could add a class to the label elements. You cannot style an element depending on the following sibling

Comment: i can definitely use class but i should be able to fix it without using class , right

Comment: You should use the `for` attribute, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, you can't select parent element.

You would have to either add container with custom class or do some sort of javascript solution